resolvconf -u option is removed in Ubuntu 24.04 version
Quesion: resolvconf -u option is removed in Ubuntu 24.04 version
Ubuntu 24.04
systemd 255 (255.4-1ubuntu8.4)
resolvconf -u

Switch -u ignored.

In the resolvconf manpage it's saying
-u, -I, -i, -l, -R, -r, -v, -V, --enable-updates, --disable-updates, --are-updates-enabled
These switches are not supported** and the command will fail if used.

I'm asking this because in the 22.04 version,
we added the following timeout option in the file /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
options timeout:1 attempts:5

Then run resolvconf -u to update.
The purpose is to have this not being overwriten in /etc/resolv.conf while restarting the systemd-resolved.service.
If the resolvconf -u is not feasible anymore, how should we correctly set a timeout and attempts options in the 24.04 version?
Thanks a lot!

Any answer on this?
